# Arrow active link

Tags: php, css, wordpress, html-lists, nav

I'm trying to add an arrow to the left hand side of my active link in my categories sidebar for my wordpress site I'm building.

I've already put in the css for it to behave the way I'd like it, I've added a small change in colour just so I know it's working well.

I've attempted to add a background image with a small .png file and tried various CSS styling to get it how I want it but I've had no luck even showing the image.

I'm open to using the character such as "➤" or the like if I cannot use a background image, maybe I might be missing something.

http://94.23.211.70/~cewp/product-category/cushions/

The above my my URL that will go directly to the page you're wanting to see along with a link already highlighted on the sidebar.

Here is the css that is making this active:

```
.product-categories .current-cat a {
color: #000033;
background-image: url("images/ICONNAMEHERE.png");
}
```

Hopefully this is enough information to provide, anymore then just ask me.

Regards

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Looks like the image is 404'ing

Comment: The icon I used is just from the top bar nav, I wanted to see if it'd appear so I can further play around with it. I'll look into the 404.

Comment: Looks like a path issue to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by css and font awesome. First add font awesome to your project. You can also use unicode charecters instead.

```
.widget_product_categories li { margin-left: 2.5em; }

.widget_product_categories li:before { 
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -2.5em; 
    font-family: 'fontawesome';
    font-size: 14px;
    content: "\f054"; 
  }
```

if not interested in adding font awesome `content:url("images/ICONNAMEHERE.png");`